# HIt counter in JSF

Tags: jsf, counter, hit

I want to add a hit counter to my JSF web app. Like in PHP we can use an external text file to store the count and increment and write it on every request. How to use in JSF?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to just use a `Filter` for this. Implement `javax.servlet.Filter` accordingly and map this in `web.xml` on an `url-pattern` of interest.

E.g. (semi pseudo):

```
public void doFilter(request, response) {
    int count = readCountFromFile();
    count++;
    writeCountToFile(count);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

The [Java IO tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) may be of help how to read and write file contents.

You don't necessarily need JSF for this. JSF is just built on top of Servlet API and you can use Filters as good with it. Otherwise you have to create a bean and you have to remember to ensure that *every* view calls this bean somehow on *every* request.

Comment: the fact of writing to a file, would it be performance issue ?? the fact of accessing each time the disk is slow.

Comment: @neo: That's not covered by the question in its current form. OP explicitly asked to write to disk.

Comment: Ok I was trying to implement a hit counter and when I saw your answer I made a comment to make things clearer for me ... I think that I'll implement it using a map with elements for each page (as a cache) and flush results to the database periodically something like one time per day.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, but the only situation that I can think for it would be for homework. Anyway, just have a Backing Bean that reads/increments/writes the file.

Look at [Apache Commons IO FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) for some good helper methods. Although if this is homework you will no doubt get better marks for rolling your own ;-)